# IEだとaudioのprogressイベントが発火しない

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
audio.volume = 0.2;
audio.play();

$(audio).on('progress', function()
{
  console.log('progress');
});
```

Chromeではprogressログが表示されますが、IE9〜11では表示されません。
解決方法があれば教えてください。

Comment: IE使っていないので試してませんが、[これ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh772923(v=vs.85).aspx) によるとIE9から対応しているように思えます。 [この](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ff974168(v=vs.85).aspx)サンプルコードでは`addEventListener`を使ってますので試してみたらどうでしょうか。

Comment: 自己解決しました。互換表示をさせない指定をしたところ上記コードでも動きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決したのでここに書いておきます。

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

互換表示のせいでした。